# App crashes, Xcode 11.5, Swift 5. NSInternalInconsistencyException .... Use the statusBarManager object on the window scene instead

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, exception

I wanted to update my app after a while, but now it crashes.

I get the following as an error message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'App called -statusBar or -statusBarWindow on UIApplication: this code must be changed as there's no longer a status bar or status bar window. Use the statusBarManager object on the window scene instead.'

What should I do? Do I have to change something in class `AppDelegate`?

class AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import CoreData
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true 
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    return true
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String?, annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

    return handled
}
}
```

I have updated XCode. Cocoapods has been updated. My Mac is up to date. I don't know what to do at the moment. I read that it is probably related to the new IOS 13 .. ...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you **read** the reason? It's pretty descriptive and includes even a solution.

Comment: Thank you. I've seen it now. Sometimes a day is just too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is very explicit and clear:

> 'App called -statusBar or -statusBarWindow on UIApplication: this code must be changed as there's no longer a status bar or status bar window. Use the statusBarManager object on the window scene instead.

Find the offending call, somewhere in `TagebuchViewController`, and remove/replace it.

Comment: Oh man, I think I need a break :-). You were absolutely right.